# Rails 'forgets' class between initializer and queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I'm encountering a peculiar issue on Rails.

We've set up a `Hook` class to handle a small pub/sub mechanism inside our app it goes something like this

```
class Hook
  @subscriptions = {}

  class << self
    def subscribe(message, &block)
      @subscriptions[message] ||= []
      @subscriptions[message] << block
    end

    def publish(message)
      @subscriptions[message].each(&:call)
    end
  end
end
```

(It's a tiny bit more fleshed out but you get the idea).

The problem is:

In an initializer we've got `Hook.subscribe(:change) { ... }`
But when the model calls `Hook.publish(:change)`, nothing happens. A quick check shows that until `Hook` is called again by the model, a `defined? Hook` returns `nil`.

The code in the model is

```
after_commit do
  # byebug
  Hook.publish(:change)
end
```

Even weirder: In the initializer I set up a global variable to hold the constant `$hook = Hook`, the constant is indeed here inside the `$hook` variable in the model but doesn't match the Hook it autoloads.

```
# inside a debugger in the model

> defined? Hook
=> nil

> $hook
=> Hook

> Hook # will trigger autoloading
=> Hook

> defined? Hook
=> "constant"

> Hook == $hook
=> false

> Hook.instance_variable_get(:@subscriptions)
=> {}

> $hook.instance_variable_get(:@subscriptions)
=> { change: [<Proc:...>] }

> Hook.object_id == $hook.object_id
=> false
```

If I set it back as the constant `Hook = $hook` through the debugger everything behaves properly again — the constant is maintained with the proper variables across requests, even.

I'm reaching the end of my wits here. As anybody got any idea what might be going on?

Comment: can you post the code where you are using this Hook class?

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize it with `$hook=Hook.new

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy: I added the code, it's pretty basic though, a simple callback.
@ChenKinnrot: We don't need to instantiate it because we use it as a single central object, we don't need it as a class _per se_, only as a constant that we'll be able to call on.
@Stefan: I forgot the `class << self` in my simplified Hook class. My bad.

Comment: Do both calls (`subscibe` and `publish`) happen in the same request?

Comment: Try running your rails app with `cache_classes=true` (and eager_load too)

Comment: @spickermann: No, the `subscribe`  happens in an initializer, so at the app boot. The  `publish` is the only part that happens inside the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a fix, even if I don't fully understand it (I'm still a bit unclear on how Rails handles autoloading I guess — I'll need to investigate deeper when I have the time).

The `Hook` class was inside a module (`OurApp::Hook`) which I had omitted for clarity in the example I shared (my mistake, obviously).
I noticed that `OurApp.constants` was losing a few constants other than `Hook`.
I went inside `lib/our_app.rb` and modified it so:

```
module OurApp
  autoload :Hook, 'lib/our_app/hook.rb'
  # ...
end
```

That seems to do the trick, no more issues.

Thanks everybody !